# AIR lock native window position

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'd like to create a window which is not allowed to move.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) with it's `systemChrome` property set to `NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE`. That way there is no possibility to move the window by native methods (dragging the title bar, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure these are set in your application.xml

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
<minimizable>false</minimizable>
<maximizable>false</maximizable>
<resizable>false</resizable>
```

Otherwise on windows you can hit the windows key + arrow to minimise / move the window around.

Comment: does that also disable `Alt+Space - Move`?

Answer (score 0):

You might also set [NativeWindow.x/y](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#x) to same value in ENTER_FRAME for example.

Comment: Just want to point out, that this is a very bad solution. It creates lots of unnecessary load for the machine.

Comment: And by lots you mean ...? Because you actually tested that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to still have the system Chrome and everything, you can listen for the NativeWindowBoundsEvent that you don't want (NativeWindowBoundsEvent.MOVE, RESIZE, etc) and make a listening function like this...

```
private function onWindowBoundsChange(evt:NativeWindowBoundsEvent):void {
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

That way, you could turn it on or off whenever you want.